# What is QGIS private cloud?

Tags: references, qgis-cloud

I am working on a conservation project involving rare species and we have a lot of sensitive data and about 50 people to whom we need to supply maps to.  At least at this stage we can not justify paying for the Pro version of QGIS Cloud.

I now see mention of QGIS Cloud Private but the details are scanty.  It sounds as if you have your own infrastructure then you can use it but there are no details.  We have IT expertises and resources.

Can someone point  me to some detailed documents on this option?

Answer (score -1):

You could export/save your maps (QQGIS Projects) in a normal sharehoster like Dropbox, MEGA, Owncloud, Nextcloud (or even on GitHub if versioning is important)

Exporting your different maps in the Format of GeoPackage would be the way to go: All layers are saved in one kind of zip-file, you can even save the QGIS project file within that package (works only with QGIS 3.8 afaik), which makes sure everyone sees the data as you do.